# Error on extension direct_mail with tables

Tags: typo3

I've fresh-installed the extension direct_mail on a TYPO3 4.6.12, but when i open the "Developer Information" tab I see this message in red:

```
Table error!
One or more required fields/tables are probably missing in the database
```

Which im guessing is associated to the error I get when i click "Invoke Mailer Engine":

```
Uncaught TYPO3 Exception
Address in mailbox given [@localhost] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2. 

...
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Install tool` > `Database Analyser` > `COMPARE` to check if all required tables and fields from extensions where applied correctly.

Sometimes there are some typos in extensions which causes that even if you'll check all tables to create, all fields to alter etc. they still appears on the COMPARE list (after refresh). In such case you need to apply each SQL statement in your favorite DB GUI - most probably it will display you an error message, why it wasn't possible to apply the change. Resolve it or contact the extension author or at least add this error to your question.

Edit:

as far as I remember second (email) error is caused by incorrect configuration of the `direct_mail` - most probably you didn't enter the sender's email, or it's invalid. Check it in the BE:

`DIRECT MAIL` > `Configuration` > *select DM folder* > `SET DEFAULT VALUES FOR DIRECT MAILS HEADERS` > `Sender email`

Comment: About the 2nd bug, I changed what you said, and so far I didnt have that problem again. Thanks

Comment: But in the first bug, even though the install tool tries to update some tables, the bug persists